# Is it possible to insert unicode strings with input VB6 control's in a SQL Database?

Tags: sql-server, unicode, vb6

I am trying to Insert Unicode strings into a table using the Internal vb6 controls(text,List,ect..) .
But when I try to do that , VB6 Control's convert that string , and different string is stored.
Am I forgetting something or is it a visual studio issue?

Comment: The most convenient Unicode-aware replacement for a TextBox is the InkEdit control.  These can be placed into text-only mode to turn of the handwriting recognition feature.  They are basically ink-enabled RichEdit controls but work for plain text as well.  Included with the OS in XP Tablet Edition, Vista and later.

Comment: @Bob77 The inkEdit control available for VB6?

Comment: Sure, that's the main reason that the ActiveX control exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a reference to a software package(3rd-party controls) :
http://www.cyberactivex.com/UniSuiteFree.htm
I used This package and it done , but would also be curious to hear feedback from anyone who has used these or other ones :)

Answer (score -1):

Original VB6 forms components did not do a good job with Unicode, although once you get Unicode strings into VB6 code you are mostly ok. You need to use the 'B' forms of string operators, like midb(), lenb() etc if you are doing any string maniputaion. You also may want to check your SQL parameter declarations to ensure you are using the unicode options. Otherwise it is all do-able.

Try the advise at [this MS Support article.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/193540/how-to-read-and-display-unicode-string-on-visual-basic-form)

Edit: After prompting from @Bob I read the MS Support article I linked to in more detail and take the point that forms2 is not a great bet for VB6 forms unless you have a more-than-usual level of control over the target machines.

In my own case I used a commercial component named Unitools from Woodbridge Associates but I cannot find their website today. Unitools included Unicode-aware label, text box, combo and list controls. Anyone able to provide a link ?

Comment: Forms 2.0 controls should not generally be used since they have many issues as described in the MS KB article.  The "B" forms of String functions are not relevant here either.